# access local files through jquery doc viewer

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am writing a small application using backbone, jquery and node. As part of the application, i want to list files on browser. When user clicks on any file, i want to open up a doc viewer window.

I tried some plugins like google doc viewer, jquery plugin etc. But not able to access files on my system.

Is it possible to access local files with available plugin. Do i need to add any headers as part of the request to specify it as doc viewer request.

I am new to jquery and front end technologies. Can someone explains with little patience.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it, but if you're trying to create an "in browser" local file browser, a users local computer is off limits for security reasons, so that's not possible, the closest you'll get is opening a file upload window ?

Comment: So you mean, we cannot access the files directly unless we upload to browser or host somewhere and give its url ?

Comment: Exactly, a website doesn't really have access to the local computer, that would be an early christmas gift to hackers.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Actually i red in some posts about this. But posted to get confirmation.. Thankyou verymuch.

Comment: If i want to host files on node server, what is the best way ?